# How to download and install 'Ubuntu for Android'

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

I searched a lot but didn't got any link to download 'Ubuntu for android'. Also, i am not talking about getting 'Ubuntu touch', it replaces android os rather than just running when phone is docked like 'Ubuntu for android' do.

Comment: if your device supports ubuntu then it can be downloaded

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu for Android, will not replace android by Ubuntu touch and not available for inside andriod for every devices. You can buy Ubuntu phones. Click [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone). To get Ubuntu phone [register here](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/register).

Some selected devices only allow you to install Ubuntu(Example: Nexus 4, 10). To know about it visit [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install).

If you have the device listed below,

Nexus 4,
 Nexus 10,
 Nexus 7 2013 WiFi, 
 Galaxy Nexus,
 Nexus 7,
 Emulator.

[watch this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnS19EPnezo) to know how to install Ubuntu Touch.